# Fiddler: blocking (filtering out) a specific page

Tags: fiddler

I want to filter out a specific page from showing up in the sessions list.  I'm not talking about filtering out entire domains/ hosts (using the filters tab) nor am I talking about actually blocking the page from loading (which can be done with an extension) - I just don't want to SEE this page in the sessions list.  10x.

Answer (score 9):

Rules > Customize Rules. Scroll to OnBeforeRequest. Add the following block:

```
if (oSession.fullUrl == "http://whatever/whatever"){
  oSession["ui-hide"] = "do not want to see";
}
```

Comment: This if statement should be interesting to VS2015 users, when using Fiddler:



`if (oSession.fullUrl.Contains("localhost:49155"))`

Answer (score 3):

I use this at the beginning of my **OnBeforeRequest** function. It's a little more sophisticated - not only does it filter out the rows for the specified page, it also filters out rows for any requests generated by the filtered page.

```
function RequestContains (uri:String) {
    return oSession.uriContains(uri) || oSession.oRequest.headers.ExistsAndContains("Referer", uri);
}
if (
    false
    ||  RequestContains("url1.aspx")
    ||  RequestContains("url2.aspx")
    ||  RequestContains("url3.aspx")
    ||  RequestContains("url4.aspx")
    ||  RequestContains("url5.aspx")
    ||  RequestContains("service1.svc")
    )
    oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
```

I put the **false** at the beginning of the if-block so that I can easily and safely comment out any of the **RequestContains** lines if I temporarily need to see those requests.

I'd love to somehow get this pattern into a UI extension to the Filters tab, where I could manage a list of these URLs without having to edit the FiddlerScript. Anyone know how to do that from within the FiddlerScript code itself?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to filter out sessions containing static content such as images & javascript. This is what I used:

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {

    if (
        oSession.uriContains(".png") ||
        oSession.uriContains(".js") ||
        oSession.uriContains(".gif") ||
        oSession.uriContains(".jpg") ||
        oSession.uriContains(".css") ||
        oSession.uriContains(".woff") ||
        oSession.uriContains(".ttf") ||
        oSession.uriContains(".ico")
    ){
        oSession["ui-hide"] = "1";
    }
```